# VB.NET - mysql check if timestart and timeend entered from vb.net conflicts with the time_start and time_end from mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I have two datetimepicker that is formatted to time only (e.g. 07:30 AM).

When I enter a time in this two datetimepicker it should prompt if the time conflicts from the mysql time_start and time_end columns (even if it is a 1 min. time conflict).

Example: 
Winform, I enter

timestart: 06:00 AM

timeend: 08:00 AM

In mysql I have:

```
 | time_start | time_end |
 | 06:00 AM   | 07:00 AM |
```

When I enter button, It should prompt me that the time I entered is conflicting with the time from mysql (some instances that it will prompt me with that time in mysql is (06:01 AM - 06:59 AM) OR (06:59 AM - 07:01 AM) OR (05:00 AM - 09:00 AM), etc.

What I have tried is this

```
'reader.GetDateTime(2) is time_start
'reader.GetDateTime(3) is time_end

Public Function checkConflict() As Boolean
    Dim conflict As Boolean = False
    sqlconn.Open()

    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_schedule ORDER BY section_id, day, time_start"
    sqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconn)
    reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        For x As Integer = 1 To daycount
            If dt_Start.Value >= reader.GetDateTime(2) And dt_End.Value <= reader.GetDateTime(3) Then
                conflict = True
            End If
        Next
    End While

    sqlconn.Close()
    Return conflict
End Function
```

How I use the function

```
If checkConflict() = False Then
    MsgBox("No conflict")
Else
    MsgBox("There is conflict")
End If
```

Comment: `two datetimepicker that is formatted to time only` that just means that it *displays* the time only.  The `Value` is still `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

For x As Integer = 1 To daycount
            If dt_Start.Value >= reader.GetDateTime(2) And dt_End.Value <= reader.GetDateTime(3) Then
                conflict = True
            End If

what is that daycount? did you make this work?